# Confused about Netty's generic types used in GenericFutureListener?

Tags: java, generics, netty

In netty define the listener as below:
for example in the class io.netty.util.concurrent.CompleteFuture:

```
@Override
public Future<V> addListener(GenericFutureListener<? extends Future<? super V>> listener) {
    if (listener == null) {
        throw new NullPointerException("listener");
    }
    DefaultPromise.notifyListener(executor(), this, listener);
    return this;
}
```

From what I've known：Future<? super V> means a collections of Class which supers V. So it is a collections as in the inheritance tree, for we have Future<V> and Future<Object> at least. Let's say the collections' name is C.

So here comes the question, what does ? extends C means while C is a collection?

Hope somebody could enlighten me!

Comment: Well, the code is taken out of context, is that declaration from Netty's [Promise](https://netty.io/4.0/api/io/netty/util/concurrent/Promise.html) class?

Comment: @EdwinDalorzo hi, I edited the question, please take a look.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm assuming your declaration above comes from Netty's [Promise](https://netty.io/4.0/api/io/netty/util/concurrent/Promise.html) class. I think my answer should work irrespective of that because your question seems to be about covariance and contravariance more than about Netty's API explicitly.

```
public interface Promise<V> extends Future<V> {

   Promise<V> addListener(GenericFutureListener<? extends Future<? super V>> listener);
   //...
}
```

The intention of generics here is to make the API more malleable for its users.

Suppose you have three different `GenericFutureListener` objects of three different type arguments: `Integer`, `Number` and `Object`.

```
GenericFutureListener<Future<Integer>> fl1 = System.out::println;
GenericFutureListener<Future<Number>> fl2 = System.out::println;
GenericFutureListener<Future<Object>> fl3 = System.out::println;
```

Notice that `Integer` is a subtype of `Number` which in turn is a subtype of `Object`.

Suppose now that we have a `Promise` of type `Integer`, somewhat as follows

```
Promise<Integer> p = somePromise;
```

Our method declaration would be interpreted by the compiler as

```
Promise<Integer> addListener(GenericFutureListener<? extendsFuture<? super Integer>> listener);
```

Which basically is saying that the `GenericFutureListener` might operate on futures of type `Integer`, *or any of its super types*.

This clearly makes the API much more flexible, for example, I can add any of the listeners I defined before to be notified when my promise of Integer is resolved:

```
p.addListener(fl1);
p.addListener(fl2);
p.addListener(fl3);
```

Notice that I was not forced to provide a listener for a future of explicitly type `Integer`. If you think about it that totally makes sense because if my promise `p` produces an `Integer`, and an `Integer` *is a* `Number`, then a listener that knows how to handle a future of `Number` should be able to handle a future of `Integer` as well. And if I have listener that knows how to handle a future of `Object`, and an `Integer` *is an* `Object`, then there should be no problem in letting a listener for a future of `Object` to handle a future of `Integer`, right?

Well, that's exactly what `Future<? super V>` means in the declaration above. This is concept known as contravariance.

Now, the truth is that in Netty `Future` is an interface, and many different classes may implement `Future`. We would like our `GenericFutureListener` to be able to use any subtype of `Future` and not just `Future` itself, right?.

For example, a `Promise` is in fact a subtype of `Future`:

```
GenericFutureListener<Promise<Integer>> fl4 = System.out::println;
GenericFutureListener<Promise<Number>> fl5 = System.out::println;
GenericFutureListener<Promise<Object>> fl6 = System.out::println;
```

And as you can see, `GenericFutureListener` accepts `Promise` as a type argument here. This is so thanks to the declaration of `<? extends Future>`.  Without it, `GenericFutureListener` would only accept the `Future` type here and that would make this API much less flexible, right?.

This concept is called covariance and once again it is used to make the API much more flexible for its users.

Now we can make our original promise also add these second set of listeners:

```
p.addListener(fl4);
p.addListener(fl5);
p.addListener(fl6);
```

And there you have it. A much more flexible API thanks to the proper use of covariance and contravariance.

Comment: Great explanation! Much clearer now, Thank you so much Edwin!  I would spend some time absorbing your idea, it is of great help!

Comment: Hi Edwin, after I carefully checked your answer, here comes another question. The declaration of <? extends> make the addListener method of promise<V> accepts certain class extends Future. So it will also accept the subClass of promise<V>, for example ChannelPromise<V>, during the execution of the listener we will get a cast exception.  This kinds of lost the point in "<? extends>" or "<? super>" in this context, for the programer will still care about the generic type of the listener, we lost the check ability provided by the compiler! I am wondering if there is a better way to write this?

Comment: @JohnMilton I'm having a hard time following your question. It is hard for me to see how it is that you'd get a ClassCastException in a case like what you mention.