# How to use method reference as future callback?

Tags: java, generics, netty

When I try to use something like this

```
class Example {
    ...

    private Future<String> asyncMethod() {
        ...
        return somePromise;
    }

    private static void callback(Future<String> future) {
        System.out.println(future.getNow());
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        asyncMethod().addListener(Example::callback);
    }
}
```

I get an error

```
Example.java:[17,34] incompatible types: invalid method reference
   incompatible types: io.netty.util.concurrent.Future<capture#1 of ? super java.lang.String>
   cannot be converted to io.netty.util.concurrent.Future<java.lang.String>
```

There are no errors with an anonymous class as the listener

```
asyncMethod().addListener(new GenericFutureListener<Future<String>>() {
    @Override
    public void operationComplete(Future<String> future) throws Exception {
        System.out.println(future.getNow());
    }
});
```

But it's ugly and verbose :( What can I do to solve this problem in the most elegant way?

Comment: What happens if you replace `callback(Future<String> future)` with `callback(Future<? super String> future)`?

Comment: @MCEmperor `incompatible types: Future<capture#1 of ? super String> cannot be converted to Future<? extends String>)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The options you have are either:

1. **use a lambda** (shorter than a full anonymous class, but still not optimal):

`asyncMethod().addListener((GenericFutureListener<Future<String>>) future -> Application.callback(future))`

2. **Fix the parameter of your callback** to:

`private static void callback(Future<? super String> future) {`

from simple `Future<String> future`, this way you can use callback too.

Note: If you are getting confused about the `? extends vs ? super` generics issue, I have [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34077112/821786) bookmarked for the same reason.

Comment: No, same problem `incompatible types: capture#1 of ? super String cannot be converted to String`.

Comment: @Hivemaster, I tried both before I posted my answer. They are compiling nicely. This is on Java 1.8.0_161, but I do not think later versions would differ in this. Can you check again?

Comment: I rechecked, you are right, now the error occurs in another place - at `future.getNow()`.

Comment: It works if I add an explicit cast to String but it looks like a crutch.

Comment: @Hivemaster, This post: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48393422/821786 gives one explanation on why this usage of generics in this case is a good choice. Nevertheless I am with you. I do not like the implementation as it is, but I think *you will need to* use one of these crutches, simply because you are forced to by the library.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I'll wait a little more before choosing the answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can cast method reference

```
asyncMethod().addListener((GenericFutureListener<Future<String>>) Example::callback);
```

It's less verbose but still not perfect. To improve this solution a little you can move long type definition to the functional interface

```
class Example {
    @FunctionalInterface
    private interface Callback extends GenericFutureListener<Future<String>> {
        void operationComplete(Future<String> future) throws Exception;
    }

    private static void callback(Future<String> future) {
        System.out.println(future.getNow());
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        asyncMethod().addListener((Callback) Example::callback);
    }
}
```

Or you can wrap callback to lambda with a typed argument

```
asyncMethod().addListener((Future<String> f) -> callback(f));
```

Maybe it can be done better, IDK.